# Android library project with maven dependencies

Tags: android, maven, android-library

I have created android library project with some depndencies managed by maven.

Now I'm trying to run library code from android maven application project.

Code I wrote in library runs, but I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError on first call to dependecy.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: What does the logcat say when running the app? AndroidManifest.xml correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what information you need... Logcat throws NoClassDefFoundError with pointed particular class from dependencies in message. No errors in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at http://androidkickstartr.com/. This tool will create correctly mavenized project for you and you can then copy missing parts from pom.xml.

Comment: From what I've read on the page You linked, it sets up application project. I know how to set android application with maven, problems begun when I created android library project.

Comment: Yes. It can create mavenized project with library project. Btw. Eclipse + android + maven + apklib doesn't work well from my experience. Prefer command line compilation and running.